# Linq for 2 collection simultaneously

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists:

```
List<A> listA1 = GetFirstList();
List<A> listA2 = GetSecondList();
```

and `class A` definition

```
class A
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime ModifiedDate {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
}
```

I am doing something based on some condition as below.

```
List<A> listA1 = GetFirstList();
List<A> listA2 = GetSecondList();
List<A> result = new List<A>();
for(int i = 0; i < listA1; i++)
{
    if(listA1[i].ModifiedDate != listA2[i].ModifiedDate)
    {
        result.Add(listA1[i]);
    }
}
```

**Assumption:** both list with contain same number of items with `Id` and `Type` in same sequence. That's why I am just checking `ModifiedDate` and rest is handled automatically because of item count and order.

I changed it using `LINQ` as below and it is working fine.

```
var match = ListA1
      .Where(a => listA2.First(ct => ct.Id == a.Id).ModifiedDate != a.ModifiedDate);
result.AddRange(match);
```

but it will iterate over both `ListA1` and `ListA2` but in first case it was iterating only once.

My question is, can I do `LINQ` by keeping index of other collection? In other words can I make `LINQ` more optimized than it is now?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Incorrect, this is hypothetical code which is off-topic for Code Review.  Please recognize what is on-topic for a site before you recommend migration.

Comment: @syb0rg how is this hypothetical?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath See this [Code Review Meta post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/27623) for more information.

Comment: Relevant sections being "It has been stripped of all context" and "The question is based on a true story — in other words, it's fictitious, hypothetical code"

Comment: @cFrozenDeath The typename `A` is a strong indicator. Also the fact that the code is very trimmed down to only the problem at hand implies that this is not the actual code (especially in a larger context) which would be required for [codereview.se]

Comment: @syb0rg I see, will take it into account. Thank you

Comment: @cFrozenDeath If you have more questions, feel free to ask them [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Zip` to link two sequences by index:

```
List<A> result = listA1.Zip(listA2, (a1, a2) => new { a1, a2 })
    .Where(x => x.a1.ModifiedDate != x.a2.ModifiedDate)
    .Select(x => x.a1)
    .ToList();
```

This will work even if both sequences don't implement `IList`/`IList<T>`, so the items can't be accessed by index.

Comment: Make it one liner!

Comment: @AdrianIftode: it is one statement. Why should i force people to scroll if they can have it in a readable way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this one liner:

```
List<A> result = listA1.Where((t, i) => t.ModifiedDate != listA2[i].ModifiedDate).ToList();
```

Comment: Has two drawbacks. Throws an exception if the second collection is smaller and requires a collection-type that implements `IList<t>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I'm also surprised to get the accept mark. May I draw your attention to the fact that OP states : *Assumption: both list with **contain same number of items*** and he uses `List<A>` as input (which implements `IList<t>`, doesn't it?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use listA1.Except(listA2, cmp) where cmp is an IComparer. Something like:

```
void Main()
{
    List<A> listA1 = new List<A> {
       new A { Id=1, ModifiedDate=new DateTime(2016,1,1), Type="A"},
       new A { Id=2, ModifiedDate=new DateTime(2016,1,2), Type="A"},
       new A { Id=3, ModifiedDate=new DateTime(2016,1,3), Type="A"},
       new A { Id=4, ModifiedDate=new DateTime(2016,1,4), Type="A"},
    };
    List<A> listA2 = new List<A> {
       new A { Id=1, ModifiedDate=new DateTime(2016,1,1), Type="A"},
       new A { Id=2, ModifiedDate=new DateTime(2016,1,2), Type="A"},
       new A { Id=3, ModifiedDate=new DateTime(2016,1,3), Type="A"},
       new A { Id=4, ModifiedDate=new DateTime(2016,1,5), Type="A"},
       new A { Id=5, ModifiedDate=new DateTime(2016,1,6), Type="A"},
       new A { Id=6, ModifiedDate=new DateTime(2016,1,7), Type="A"},
    };

    var cmp = new AEqualityComparer();
    var result = listA1.Except(listA2, cmp);

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id:{0}, Date:{1}",item.Id, item.ModifiedDate);
    }
}

public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class AEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<A>
{
    public bool Equals(A x, A y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.ModifiedDate == y.ModifiedDate;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(A obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't keep track of the index here, it's not the same code anymore

Comment: Yes I don't. This code is free from the assumption of same number of iterms and order. That was a dangerous assumption on my part. Comparing only the dates without thinking Id is not very realistic in real life (very much contrainted to special cases).